# Can i save a received message on some sort of persistent storage on my Watchos 3

Tags: swift3, watchos-3

Can someone help me?
is it posible to store a variable on the local storage of my watch, so my app can read those settings as it starts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and you have several options. The best choice mostly depends on what kind of information you want to store. If it's just a single variable, the easiest way is to store it in either the Info.plist file of your app or to store it in a file.
If you want to store more complex data, you can store it in a database.